Are Value Classes allowed to exhibit change?
The doc for Value Based Classes specify:

Instances of a value-based class:

are final and immutable (though may contain references to mutable objects);


If I defined a value class Foo, which had a mutable member Bar:
value class Foo {
    Bar bar; // Bar is a mutable type
}

Then introduced a method which queried one of  Bar methods, which may return different results (for example, an int value which may change):
public int number() {
    return bar.number(); // may return different results!
}

Would this be an improper use of a Java value class?
JEP 401 mentions:

Simple domain values are commonly shared throughout a program, but their fields are final, so different parts of a program that have references to a given object will never observe any changes in it.

Does the fact that the change can be observed through Foo#number() mean that it is an improper to use a value class?

As I understand it:  No.  Immutable means all state is immutable, recursively.

Questions asking about how something should be used/what iss considered "improper" use are considered opinion-based and hence off-topic on Stack Overflow.

@dan1st Could you point out which part of that page would suggest a question such as "is this how the tool works?" is off topic? I'm not asking a question that requires a Java language architect/professional to intervene. I'm just trying to confirm whether I've understood the JEP properly.

"Two value objects are the same according to == if they have the same field values, regardless of when or how they were created. " I don't think your method breaks this definition.

I do not think that is a bad use of value types. I will probably use something like that for Panama's MemorySegments, so they have a type and accessors to the underlying memory.

@Vince the part saying that opinion-based questions are off-topic. You are asking about what is "improper use" but what's proper use/using a feature as it should be used is a matter of opinion. If you want to know whether something is used as the JDK devs intended, that would typically be a question only those people can answer (hence off-topic ass well).
